# Inserting multiple values into a temporary table, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, temp-tables

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I am trying to run the following query to input values into a temporary table to use later:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(colnumber varchar(15), dispcode varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #temptable (colnumber, dispcode)
VALUES 
('col5', '811'),
('col6', '817'),
('col7', '823'),
('col8', '825');
```

When running I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 50
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Which points to the line "('col5', '811'),"

Could anyone help me identify the problem here?

Comment: its working fine see here...http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/773e2/1

Comment: Which **VERSION** of SQL Server are you using? This ability to specify multiple sets of data to use in an `INSERT` was introduced with SQL Server **2008** only - it isnt' available in earlier versions.

Answer (score 15):

For SQL Server version <2008 use this:

```
INSERT INTO #temptable (colnumber, dispcode)
SELECT 'col5', '811'
UNION ALL SELECT 'col6', '817'
UNION ALL SELECT 'col7', '823'
UNION ALL SELECT 'col8', '825'
```

Comment: The weird thing is that I am using 2012, however doing it that way works for me so thanks!

Comment: You may be running in compatibility mode and using an old engine. Check it.